# Airflow Jinja Templating

Tags: python, jinja2, airflow

Trying to reference a variable in Python using the Jinja templating within Airflow to print a variable value

```
job_id = 15
print("{{ params.job_id }}")
```

However, it's printing:

`{{ params.job_id }}`

How should I trigger a proper rendering?

Comment: Share your DAG code please

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're using jinja at all. This is an example of how to use it:

```
from jinja2 import Tempate

job_id = 15
template = Template("{{ params.job_id }}")

# Method 1: pass values as a dict
params = {'job_id': job_id}
print(template.render({'params': params}))

# Method 2: pass values as keyword arguments
print(template.render(params={'job_id': job_id},))

# Method 3: one line
print(Template("{{ params.job_id }}").render({'params': {'job_id': job_id}}))
```

You can learn more about Jinja Templating in the [docs](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/) (current version is 2.11.x)